# Find the remainder when the product of first $92$ numbers is divided by $97$.

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, contest-math

From Wilson's theorem, we know that $96!mod(97) \equiv 96$ and $95!mod(97)\equiv 1$. 
We can re-write it as $(92! \times 93 \times 94 \times 95)mod(97)\equiv 1$
$\Rightarrow 92!mod(97) \times 93mod(97) \times 94mod(97) \times 95mod(97) \equiv 1$
$\Rightarrow 92!mod(97) \times -4 \times -3 \times -2 \equiv 1$
$\Rightarrow 92!mod(97) \times -24 \equiv 1$
$\Rightarrow 92!mod(97)  \equiv \frac{-1}{24}$

I am not able to proceed from here as to how to find the positive remainder as this remainder is not a valid answer it seems. Please help me on this !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: $\frac{96}{24}=4$.

Comment: You nearly finish it. You multiply the last equation by 4 will cancel the number 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Wilson’s Theorem, we have $$96!\equiv -1 \quad \pmod {97}$$
Since $ 93\times 94 \times 95 \times 96 \equiv 24$, therefore $$92!\times 24 \equiv -1 \quad  \pmod {97} \tag*{*} $$
Multiplying the equation (*) by 4 yields $$92!\times 96\equiv -4 \quad  \pmod {97} \tag*{**} $$ $$92!\times (-1)\equiv -4 \quad  \pmod {97} \tag*{**} $$
Hence we have $$92!\equiv 4 \quad  \pmod {97}$$

Comment: Okk...i got it...i didn't know that you can multiply both sides in this too!!

Comment: Because 4 and 97 are coprime, we can multiply the equation by 4.